# reduzir tamanho de uma imagem que está na base de dados

Tags: php, html, sql

tenho uma tabela que mostra o  conteudo de uma base de dados, um dos conteudos é uma imagem, chamo  a imagem da seguinte maneira: `<td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $books->Image ).'"/>'; ?> </td>`

mas a imagem aparece muito grande, gostaria de saber como faço para alterar o tamanho da imagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

olha eu nunca usei database, mas pelo que eu vi se vc usa o `<img src="">` pra chamar a imagem, então o `width` e o `height` devem funcionar, tente adiciona algo como isso aqui `<img src="" height="150" width="150">`

`<td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $books->Image ).'" height="150" width="150"/>'; ?> </td>`

Comment: obrigado deu certo

Answer (score 5):

> Devemos tomar alguns cuidados sempre que formos usar os tamanhos de uma imagem através dos atributos height e width. O principal deles, é a proporção entre a largura e a altura de uma imagem.

Se esses atributos não são conhecidos, primeiramente devemos obtê-los através da função **getimagesize do PHP**.

`list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("../images/Imagem005.jpg");`

<sub>Retorna uma matriz com 4 elementos. O índice 0 contém a largura da imagem em pixels. O índice 1 contém a altura. O índice 2 é uma indicação do tipo de imagem: 1 = GIF, 2 = JPG, 3 = PNG, 4 = SWF, 5 = PSD, 6 = BMP, 7 = TIFF(intel byte order), 8 = TIFF(motorola byte order), 9 = JPC, 10 = JP2, 11 = JPX, 12 = JB2, 13 = SWC, 14 = IFF, 15 = WBMP, 16 = XBM. Estes valores correspondem as constantes IMAGETYPE que foram adicionadas no PHP 4.3. O índice 3 é uma string com o height="yyy" width="xxx" correto que pode ser usado diretamente numa tag IMG. [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getimagesize.php)</sub>

**Como só nos interessa os atributos height e width usaremos**

```
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize("../images/Imagem005.jpg");
 //nova largura
 $newWidth = 200;

 //nova altura
 $newHeight = ($newWidth*$height)/$width;

 echo "<img src=\"../images/Imagem005.jpg\" width=\"".$newWidth."\" height=\"".$newHeight."\"/>";
```

> No seu caso a tag img ficaria assim:

```
   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $books->Image ).'" height='.$newHeight.' width='.$newWidth.'/>';
```

> Por outro lado, deixando o PHP de lado, basta indicar a largura na tag img que os navegadores calculam automaticamente a altura.

Comment: Parece-me demasiado. Eu utilizaria apenas CSS, é mais performante, e o resultado é o mesmo. Com height auto o browser calcula por nós a altura, daí precisares de menos processamento, e como é do lado do cliente é "cachable".

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar também CSS para alterar a dimensão da imagem. E recomendo que o faças de forma proporcional, ou seja, aplicavas só, p ex, a largura, assim ela não ficaria com um aspecto "forçado".

O teu código PHP com a classe de CSS resized.

```
<td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $books->Image ).'" class="resized"/>'; ?> </td>
```

Código CSS

```
.resized {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
```